# Treating move_base/goal as simple subscriber rather than ActionServer?

Tags: navigation, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello All,
I have a fairly basic question regarding utilizing move_base. I know I can publish a simple goal using move_base_simple/goal and not monitor the result. However I would like to get an update on when the goal is reached. Using an ActionClient can be a problem for me since I am commanding multiple robots from a single process. The ActionClient will block my process till the task has been completed. I was wondering if it is possible for me to publish directly the move_base/goal and then simply subscribe to the topic "move_base/result". I other words completely bypass the ActionClient and incorporate a truly publish/subscribe relation. This way I can command several robots within the same node. Please let me know if this is possible or what are other better ways?
Thanks!
Ammar

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48480/treating-move_base/goal-as-simple-subscriber-rather-than-actionserver?/) by [Ammar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2639/ammar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 289 on 2012-11-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Actionlib will certainly not block unless you want it to block. Besides the ability to preempt goals, that's one of the most important advantages of actionlib.

For instance, you can use the action client method [sendGoal](http://ros.org/doc/fuerte/api/actionlib/html/classactionlib_1_1SimpleActionClient.html#ae6a2e6904495e7c20c59e96af0d86801). It will just send the goal and return immediately.

Of course it is also possible to directly publish on the action server's goal topic. That's what actionlib does internally. I would not suggest to do that though.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ammar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2639/ammar/) on 2012-11-19**:
So if I use the action client sendGoal, will I be able to create a subscriber to listen to move_base/status or move_base/result, I would like to know when the goal gets completed as well. Thanks!

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-19**:
The action client library always subscribes to the status topic anyway. Have a look at the API docs. You can pass callbacks that are executed when a goal is done or when feedback is received.